# Finding controls with specific ID pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a bunch of `<div>`'s in my project named using the syntax `block[number]`. For example, block1, block2, block3, etc.

I want to iterate through these in the code behind, but I can't get it to work.

Basically what I want to do is to tell the code to look for the control named `block[i]`, where `i` is a counter I take care of.

I was thinking `FindControl` but I'm not sure if this will work. Thanks!

Comment: Are all those `<div>`'s have `runat="server"`? If not, you can't achieve this using code behind.

Comment: Yes, they are, thats the first think i did.

Answer (score 4):

you can use something like this in your page:

```
void IterAllBlocks(Control container, Action<Control> workWithBlock)
{
    foreach(var ctr in container.Controls.Cast<Control>)
    {
       if (ctr.Name.StartsWith("block")
          workWithBlock(ctr);
       if (ctr.Controls.Count > 0) IterAllBlocks(ctr, workWithBlock);
    }
}
```

using

```
IterAllBlocks(this, block => { /* do something with controls named "block..." here */ });
```

PS: for FindControl you need the full identifier - you can try "guessing" them with something like

```
for(i = 1; true; i++)
{
   var id = string.Format("block{0}"i);
   var ctr = this.FindControl(id);
   if (ctr == null) break;
   // do what you have to with your blocks
}
```

but I think the LINQ one reads more nicely

Comment: I think he need something "deep" that will iterate through all controls, not just direct children of the page.

Comment: I understood the second code you posted, but not the first. Thats wayy to advanced for me hehe.

The controls i need are all contained within the same div container, so i guess the second code will work for me.

Thanks, will try it out.

Comment: I changed it because of Shadow Wizards comment - looking at a container (in Webforms every Control - even a Page-object has a Controls-Collection) it just iterates all controls in it (might be empty) - then it just checks for each contained control if it's a "block" and recurivly checks all controls in this control as well. - The action is to there to allow you do do your stuff - you can to this inside the foreach-loop as well but this way you seperate your concerns more nicely.

Comment: So i wont need to use the first code if i am 100% sure my container wont contain child containers?

What i need to work with is a div container, and in it are many divs. So i just need to iterate throu one container.

Comment: I have added answer that guide you even further, based on this correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [CKoenig answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298112/finding-controls-with-specific-id-pattern/7298131#7298131), here is simpler that is working with simple List:

```
void GetAllBlocks(Control container, List<HtmlGenericControl> blocks)
{
    foreach(var ctr in container.Controls.Cast<Control>)
    {
        if (ctr.Name.StartsWith("block") && ctr is HtmlGenericControl)
            blocks.Add(ctr);
        if (ctr.Controls.Count > 0)
            GetAllBlocks(ctr, blocks);
    }
}
```

Now to use it have such code: (pnlContainer is the ID of the panel holding all the blocks)

```
List<HtmlGenericControl> blocks = new List<HtmlGenericControl>();
GetAllBlocks(pnlContainer, blocks);
foreach (HtmlGenericControl block in blocks)
{
    block.InnerHtml = "changed by code behind, id is " + block.Id;
}
```

When you become more "advanced" use the original code of the answer then have this:

```
IterAllBlocks(pnlContainer, block => {
    block.InnerHtml = "changed by code behind, id is " + block.Id;
});
```

Which will do exactly the same thing, just more elegantly.

Comment: nice - I corrected a slight copy&paste error in your recursive call

Comment: Thanks lol.. didn't notice! You gave the bricks, I built the house. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, just one more thing. How do i represend div on codebehind?

Comment: `<div id="myDiv" runat="server">` in code behind is `HtmlGenericControl myDiv;` - this is true for any HTML tag actually, not just `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl` will only work if the controls are server controls (i.e., have the attribute `runat="server"`).

You can make mark the div tags with runat="server", and then you can use FindControl on them (be aware it's not recursive, however, so if the controls are nested inside other controls you'll have to do the recursion yourself).

However, the real question is why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: I already have then using runat="server". I need to do this because im making a game and this is the way i am generating the map.

Comment: Ok.  Ckoenig's answer should work for you - or get you pointed in the right direction.